# How to intersect two ManyToMany fields with a Django Query?

Tags: django, join

Let's say I have the following Django models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)

class B(models.Model):
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
```

I have an A object. I want to find all B objects where some keyword in the B object is the same as some keyword in the A object.

What is the correct way to write this query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For my sanity, I'm replacing A and B with Article and Blog, respectively. It makes it a lot easier to parse the related names. So, we have:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)

class Blog(models.Model):
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
```

This should work, in one query:

```
article = Article.objects.all()[0]
Blog.objects.filter(keywords__in=Keyword.objects.filter(articles=article))
```

Django will combine the `Keyword.objects.filter` into the `Blog.objects.filter` query, making just one database call.

Comment: Does this result in multiple single queries or a single joined query to the database?

Comment: One query only. You can confirm with `print Blog.objects.filter(keywords__in=Keyword.objects.filter(articles=article)).query` while in the Django shell.

Comment: I actually turned query logging on to watch in the end, using SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
But the .query trick is going to be very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `a` is an instance of `A`, something like that should do:

```
B.objects.filter(keywords__pk__in=a.keywords.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

Comment: EDIT: As the querysets are _lazily_ evaluated the database will only be hit once.