# Efficient way to check for a M2M intersection in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have two objects of the same class (Model) type. I want to check for an intersection on an M2M field. Is there an efficient way to do this without using raw SQL?

Here's, basically, my current solution.

```
genres_a = [g for g in profile_a.genres.all()] # Convert to List
genres_b = set([g for g in profile_b.genres.all()]) # Convert to Set

if genres_b.intersection(genres_a): # Look for Intersection (Not Lazy)
    print True # Do something...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to intersect two ManyToMany fields with a Django Query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129431/how-to-intersect-two-manytomany-fields-with-a-django-query)

Comment: Possibly but I wasn't necessarily asking how to intersect two M2M fields -- rather looking for an efficient way to perform the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood intersection right:

```
profile_a.genres.all().filter(id__in=profile_b.genres.all())
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to give this a try, with some timing, to see if it's actually more efficient. I just need to add an .exists() on to the end of that to use it in my 'if' statement, right?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure if is more efficient, but that tells to the database makes the cartesian product, and yes you have to add .exists() for test if the sql have any results